# java.net.BindException: Address not available

Tags: java, docker, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, stress-test

I am using Gatling to load test a spring application build using Spring webflux and mongo databse. My API just takes a string parameter and does a get call on the mongo reactive repository. My application is deployed in Google cloud GKE and GCE (mongo DB).

I am running gatling as a docker container using image https://github.com/denvazh/gatling . Gatling test access the API end point over internet using public IP.

Test works fine till the load 28000 concurrent users, when I inject 30K users at once , I get 'java.net.BindException: Address not available'.  Can someone please give some idea on the issue.

I checked FD limit on both host machine and docker container , looks fine for me. I am pasting ulimit output at the end. I get below excpetion on gatling script stdout.

Request:
getEligibilityMVCSimulation: KO i.n.c.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedSocketException: Address not available: /some_ip:80
Session:
Session(getEligibilityMVCSimulation,30975,1556538559546,Map(gatling.http.ssl.sslContexts -> SslContexts(io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSslClientContext@3ff8fa07,None), gatling.http.cache.dns -> io.gatling.http.cache.DnsCacheSupport$$anon$1@5273a181, gatling.http.cache.baseUrl -> http://localhost:8182/eligibility-service/v1/),0,KO,List(),io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry$$Lambda$435/194107588@4249260d)

HTTP request:
GET http://some_ip/eligibility-service/v1/8672
headers=
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
origin: http://some_ip
host: some_ip

```
HTTP response:

11:49:30.614 [WARN ] i.g.h.e.GatlingHttpListener - Request 'getEligibilityMVCSimulation' failed for user 30983
java.net.BindException: Address not available
        ... 34 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedSocketException: Address not available: /some_ip
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:454)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:446)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:648)
        at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$3.run(SocketUtils.java:83)
        at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$3.run(SocketUtils.java:80)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils.connect(SocketUtils.java:80)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:312)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.connect(AbstractNioChannel.java:254)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.connect(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1366)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:545)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:530)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.connect(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:497)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.connect(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:47)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.connect(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:298)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:545)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:530)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.connect(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:50)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:545)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:530)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.connect(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:50)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:545)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:530)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:512)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.connect(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1024)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.connect(AbstractChannel.java:259)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$3.run(Bootstrap.java:252)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:462)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:897)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
11:49:30.614 [WARN ] i.g.h.e.r.DefaultStatsProcessor - Request 'getEligibilityMVCSimulation' failed for user 30983: i.n.c.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedSocketException: Address not available: /some_ip:80
```

I am working on GCE VM with Debian 9 stretch. Initially ulimit -n was returning 1024 and after I followed all the steps in https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/operations/ ulimit -a is returning as 65535. But I am getting same exception.

```
ulimit -a gives below result,

joy123456@gatling-tests-vm-2:~$ ulimit -a


core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 60087

max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024

pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 60087

virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

I checked ulimit on docker container, and it gives below result,

```
joy123456@gatling-tests-vm-2:~$ 
sudo docker run -it --entrypoint sh denvazh/gatling


/opt/gatling # ulimit -a


-f: file size (blocks)             unlimited
-t: cpu time (seconds)             unlimited
-d: data seg size (kb)             unlimited
-s: stack size (kb)                8192
-c: core file size (blocks)        unlimited
-m: resident set size (kb)         unlimited
-l: locked memory (kb)             64
-p: processes                      unlimited
-n: file descriptors               1048576
-v: address space (kb)             unlimited
-w: locks                          unlimited
-e: scheduling priority            0
-r: real-time priority             0
```

Can someone please give some idea on the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Issue was related VM I was running gatling.  I had to  enable few TCP properties like port reuse and recycle. It allowed me send 500K concurrent requests.

Comment: which settings did you change on VM?

Answer (score 0):

try gatling `shareConnections`
e.g

```
val httpConf = http
    .baseURL("http://IP:8080")
    .acceptHeader("text/html,application/xhtml+xml")
    .acceptLanguageHeader("en-US,en;q=0.5")
    .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate")
    .shareConnections
```